# Which Tag in Json file to fetch the YouTube Video on Android application on ListView Item?

Tags: android, youtube-api

Here is my json file i use thumbnail on listview but there no such tag that fetch videos . Define it which tag i use ?
That perfectly add thumbnail or other things

Below is my preview of Listview items

[image]

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "etag": "\"GM4ZnRh2gk1X1BLWgHklTm-3cgQ/uvcwjZ_9_NYCLF7JAzfY5FiuzuQ\"",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1998,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
      "etag": "\"GM4ZnRh2gk1X1BLWgHklTm-3cgQ/dCBViPWfe-MGrqHIcuMZ55HcLJ0\"",
      "id": "VVVHaENWR1owWlNwZTVoSkhXeWlMd0hBLlZHRHFaakFMSF9N",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2017-01-26T08:58:26.000Z",
        "channelId": "UCGhCVGZ0ZSpe5hJHWyiLwHA",
        "title": "Top 10 - Scariest scenes in Resident evil 7",
        "description": "Resident Evil 7 brings the series back to its roots while mak Epidemic Sound.\nhttp://www.epidemicsound.com/youtube-creator-subscription/",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VGDqZjALH_M/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
        },
        "channelTitle": "ZoominGames",
        "playlistId": "UUGhCVGZ0ZSpe5hJHWyiLwHA",
        "position": 0,
        "resourceId": {
          "kind": "youtube#video",
          "videoId": "VGDqZjALH_M"
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: do you want to get video URl from youtube?

Comment: yes i didn't found the url in Json file .

Comment: youtube does not give video URLs. It works another way. To see how it works - see official tutorial.

Comment: youtube give us video Id?

Comment: don't you see `videoId` in your JSON?

Comment: You cannot get video link but to play the video you have to use youtubeplayer widget .

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is true that you cannot find any url in the json output. The only thing that you can get from here is the `videoId`.

You can use this `videoId` as part of this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="insert_videoId" to get a video link.

So in your case, this is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGDqZjALH_M